# How can I make a button circular while not affecting the content in the button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pager HTML

```css
.pager > li > a {
    color: black !Important;
}
.pager > li > a.right-arrow {
    margin-left: 335px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #9ecaed;
    border-width: 0px;
}
.pager > li > a.left-arrow {
    margin-right: 335px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #9ecaed;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 25px;
}
.number {
    color: black !Important;
    border-color: white !Important;
    padding: 3px !Important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pager">
        <li><a href="#" class="left-arrow">➜</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">3</a></li>
        <li class="number">...</li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="right-arrow">➜</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have made the button the right circular shape I want but now the arrow inside the button moves out of the button circle. This gets fixed when removing the width height attributes but then the button isn't as circle as I want it to be. How can I solve this problem? The content isn't centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with the padding and line height you can get the what you want with `.left-arrow` add this

```
padding: 7px;
line-height: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-left: 7px;`
to `.left-arrow`

```css
.pager > li > a {
    color: black !Important;
}
.pager > li > a.right-arrow {
    margin-left: 335px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #9ecaed;
    border-width: 0px;
}
.pager > li > a.left-arrow {
    margin-right: 335px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #9ecaed;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 25px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    
}
.number {
    color: black !Important;
    border-color: white !Important;
    padding: 3px !Important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="pager">
        <li><a href="#" class="left-arrow">➜</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">3</a></li>
        <li class="number">...</li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="number">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="right-arrow">➜</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```